# Pass id to Bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I wanna pass value userID from this table to Bootstrap modal so that we can view his info. Can somebody help me how to do this?

Here is my user table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-striped" id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="center" width="5%">n</th>
            <th align="center">name</th>
            <th align="center" width="12%">Activity</th>                                  
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td><?= $i; ?>.</td>
             <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
             <td>
                 <a href="#dModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dModal" data-id="<?php echo $row['userID'] ?>" class="open-AddBookDialog btn btn-small btn-square btn-info" title="view"><i class="icon-search"></i></a>
             </td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my Bootstrap modal in same php file. I just put below table coding above and not in separate file.

```
<div id="dModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">User Info</h3>
        </div>
        <?php

          $id = $_GET['id'];
          //echo $id;

          $sql_str = "SELECT *
                      FROM
                        adm_user 
                      WHERE userID = '".$id."' ";

          echo ($sql_str);

          $res_user =   mysql_query($sql_str) or die(print_r(mysql_error()));
          $result = mysql_query($sql_str);

        ?>


        <div class="modal-body">
            // view user info here
        </div>
    </div>
```